# Reverse gas in dashboard

Tags: honda, civic, gasoline, supplemental-restraint-system, dashboard

I was visiting Honda service for my TAKATA airbag recall three days ago. After I visit, I see my gas dashboard acting weird three days in a row.

For example, for Honda Civic there are about 20 dots in gas dashboard. Normally, it will show how much gas left in your tank. If you use quarter of them, it will show 15 dots. The dots are starting from R (empty) to L (full). However, I start my engine, my car show how much gas I used instead. That means it will show five dots in this case. The dots are starting from L (full) to R (empty).

I would like to know

1. What is wrong with my gas dashboard.
2. Could it be the microcomputer? And when airbag was changed, do they touch the microcomputer? Is it possible that my gas dashboard related to airbag change?

Comment: Did you ask the dealer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @PeteCon I called dealer this morning and a lady told me I need to press a button. There are two possibilities: one is near steering wheel; the other bottom is the one change between tripA/B mile. Apparently it is not the one changing between trip A/B mile. I have no idea where the other bottom is so she says I can bring my car back to check. When I bring my car back this afternoon, the random guy says only the old model have that button and he says I need to change the whole dashboard/screen. He didn't mention whether they touch the microcomputer. He says the airbag is at passenger side.

Comment: If the dealer worked on it and now something is wrong, take it back to them to fix it. They most certainly disconnected the battery to service the airbag. This would likely reset many personal settings to default. Check your owners manual to be sure it isn't normal behavior.